# how to change the size of angular bootstrap calendar?

Tags: angular, calendar

```
<mwl-calendar-month-view>
</mwl-calendar-month-view>
```

I tried to reduce it in many ways: from the .scss file, with "style" inline,via class and without... but nothing works.
Please give me an idea how can I do this
Thanks

[This is the inspect window, I noted down here what are the lines I should remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iLts.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome back :D
In the documentation of this library, the developer says that not every component contains styles so that it is easier to overwrite them.
Somewhere here: https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/docs/index.html
But if this is the case then you must use the word "!important" after each rule.
For example:

```css
.some-example-class {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

Or try with "::ng-deep" but I'm not sure exactly how it works, something like this:

```css
::ng-deep {
  .some-example-class {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

You can also combine "::ng-deep" and "!important".

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. What I finally did is opening the angular-calendar.css file from the node-modules folder and change there. It works for some of the properties but not for all of them; for example- the square of an event in the calendar stays in it's old location and not in it's new wanted location..... If you have soluntion to that problem I'll be grateful... In any case thanks for your help

Comment: In general, for styles from different libraries to work properly and to be able to overwrite them, you should also remember to import them from node_modules to the "styles.css" global style file. Sometimes, instead of importing to styles.css, you need to import them in angular.json in the styles array (in angular.json: projects-> YourProjectName-> architect-> build-> options-> styles). Perhaps such an import is missing and therefore you cannot overwrite?

Comment: Cool! It works! I added the imports to the angular.json as you said, and then I opened the original .css file and changed the style there. **Thank you very much!**
What still doesn't work is this: I decreased the size of the calendar but the squres that show the events - stay in their last location, as if the calendar is in its old big size. I changed all the connected properties but with no results... Have any idea?

Comment: It's hard to tell without the styles and components in front of your eyes, but probably many components in this calendar are independent of each other. It is enough that one of them may have the position rule changed and it may display differently.

Comment: Yeah you right.
I followed the event square by "inspect" button and I got the exact lines that I should remove, look at the screenshot - the class="cal-day-badge ng-star-inserted" and the <span class="cal-day-badge ng-star-inserted">1</span>. When I delete them in the inspect window - so the calendar works perfectly. But how can I find this code's location in my angular so I can change it permanently? 
Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! The screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iLts.png